# pass array using intent

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

In my **Activity A**, I want to pass `results` to **Activity B**.

```
ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

 i.putExtra("resuls", results);
```

**Activity B**

```
 results=getIntent().getExtras().getString("results");
```

App crashed when  want to intent to **B**

```
 Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 3162
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.project.myapplication.bean.SearchResults@f8e8031
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1397)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:738)
```

**SearchResult**

```
public class SearchResults {

    private String weather = "";
    private String date = "";
    private String status = "";
    private String timeIn="";
    private String timeOut="";
    private String project="";
    private String description="";
    private String progress="";

    public void setWeather(String weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
        this.timeIn = timeIn;
    }

    public String getTimeIn() {
        return timeIn;
    }

    public void setTimeOut(String timeOut){
       this.timeOut=timeOut;
    }

    public String getTimeOut()
    {
        return timeOut;
    }

    public void setProject(String project){
        this.project=project;
    }

    public String getProject()
    {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProgress(String progress){
        this.progress=progress;
    }

    public String getProgress()
    {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }



}
```

How do I pass the array and finally shows them in activity B ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Either have `SearchResults` implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Step #2: Use [`getParcelableArrayList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)) or [`getSerializable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getSerializable(java.lang.String)) instead of `getString()` to retrieve the value out of the extras `Bundle`.

Comment: If I don't want to retrieve the value out, just pass only, which way should I use ?

Comment: @Seng: If you do not want to retrieve the value, do not send the value in the first place.

Comment: Use serializable for passing bean objects and also make your bean class implements serializable